# How to inherit a method properly from parent class without changing the parent class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance

I got this question from my friend who is a first year CS student.

**Question:** Implement the design of the `Xiaomi` and the `Huawei` classes that inherit
from `SmartPhone` class so that the following code generates the output below:

**Given Code:**

```
class SmartPhone:
     def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name
     def check(self):
          print(“The phone is working properly”)

     #Write your code here

f = Xiaomi(“Redmi Note 8”)
c = Huawei(“Y9”)
f.check()
print(“=========================”)
c.check()
print(“=========================”)
```

****Output should be:****

```
This is Xiaomi Redmi Note 8
The phone is working properly
=========================
This is Huawei Y9
The phone is working properly
=========================
```

**My Solution:**

```
class SmartPhone:
     def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name
     def check(self):
         print(self.__str__()) #changing parent class
         print('The phone is working properly')

#Write your code here
class Xiaomi(SmartPhone):
    def __str__(self):
        return f'This is Xiaomi {self.name}'
class Huawei(SmartPhone):
    def __str__(self):
        return f'This is Huawei {self.name}'


f = Xiaomi('“Redmi Note 8”')
c = Huawei('“Y9”')
f.check()
print('=========================')
c.check()
print('=========================')
```

My solution provides correct output as required by changing the parent class. But it was said not to change the parent class `SmartPhone` and only construct child classes to produce same result. So, how can I produce the result without changing the parent `SmartPhone` class?

Comment: `def check(self): print('This is Xiaomi ...'); super().check()`…? Override the `check` method in each child to output that additional message before calling the parent's original method…?

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot. I forgot calling the super function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to implement the `check` method calling the parent's method too:

```py
class SmartPhone:
     def __init__(self, name):
         self.name = name

     def check(self):
          print(“The phone is working properly”)


#Write your code here
class Xiaomi(SmartPhone):
    def check(self):
        print(f"This is Xiaomi {self.name}")
        super().check()


class Huawei(SmartPhone):
    def check(self):
        print(f"This is Huawei {self.name}")
        super().check()


f = Xiaomi(“Redmi Note 8”)
c = Huawei(“Y9”)
f.check()
print(“=========================”)
c.check()
print(“=========================”)
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call super when override a method from superclass. That's mean,

```
def check(self):
    print(f"This is Xiaomi {self.name}")
    super.check()
    // codes for overriding
```